# Plotting 'date' on the X-axis in R ggplot2

Tags: r

I am working on a group project and we're having trouble including **dates on the x-axis** of our time-series plots (see image). Unfortunately, our code has 600 lines and uses multiple datasets that contain stock price information so I am unable to include all the code/ data, however, we have pinpointed the line that needs to be improved.

To replicate the issue, similar data can be extracted using the following commands

```
# Get the S&P 500 companys' information
# Drop some companies due to data error
download = getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/s-and- 
p-500-companies/master/data/constituents.csv")
SP500 = read.csv(text=download)
head(SP500)
SP500 = SP500[-which(SP500$Symbol %in% 
c("BRK.B","MON","UA","WELL")),]

# Acquire stock price information with quantmod package
stock_price = list()
stock_name = NULL
for(ticker in sub_SP500$Symbol){
  print(ticker)
  stock = getSymbols(ticker,src='yahoo',from = '2015-07-01', auto.assign = F)[,4]
  stock_price = c(stock_price,list(stock))
  stock_name = c(stock_name,ticker)
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
names(stock_price) = stock_name

# normalized stock price
normalized = function(x){
  m = mean(x)
  s = sd(x)
  n = (x-m)/s
  return(n)
}
normalized_price = lapply(stock_price,function(x) normalized(x))


# Plot clusters
library(dtwclust)

normalized_price = lapply(stock_list,function(x) normalized(x))

dtw_cluster10 = tsclust(normalized_price, type="partitional",k=10,
                  distance="dtw_basic",centroid = "pam",seed=1234,trace=T,
                  args = tsclust_args(dist = list(window.size = 19)))
plot(dtw_cluster10)
```

Maybe someone has an easy fix on plotting dates on the x-axis?

[image: plot]

Comment: Guessing you are using additional unmentioned packages like `TSclust` or `dtwclust` which are relying on ggplot2. Please describe where your functions come from. Can you replicate the issue using generic data included in the package, or fake data?

Comment: Hi @JonSpring, I updated the request. Hope you can help me out!

Comment: Looks like this still requires a few more unmentioned packages like `quantmod` and undefined variables like `stock_list`. Can you pls restart R and confirm the code runs as provided?

Comment: Stepping back, doesn't dynamic time warping imply that the x axes will not relate to the same dates for multiple series in the same cluster? I'm not sure the desired output is possible.